# Class diagrams with Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

The situation that I'm in currently is that I'm trying to create a series of class diagrams to use for a c++ project. And while for the most part I'm able to do this automatically for the classes that inherit from another class or ones that have an instance of another class inside their code, I'm unable to create a diagram for the classes that don't do either of these. So I'm wondering if there is a way to create a class diagram in this case. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe this can be a starting point: https://www.google.com/search?q=create+class+diagram

Comment: going through the search results yields that the best way would be to go through another program. is it safe to assume that doxygen is unable to do this? I was hoping to stay with doxygen, as it is the primary source for the project.

Comment: I have little experience with Doxygen. I was just offering some options.

Comment: The closest Doxygen comes to class diagrams, are rectangles with the class name in them.  You may want to tools that *draw UML diagrams from C++ code*.